# Multi-folder command handler

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I'm trying to make my command handler that allows to have files inside folders. For example, I'd have a folder named `./commands/moderation` or maybe one named `./commands/fun`, etc. How can I do it?

My code looks like this but it only handles JavaScript files inside my `./commands` folder.

```js
for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`)
    client.commands.set(command.name, command)
}

// ...

if (!client.commands.has(command)) return;
try {
    client.commands.get(command).execute(message, args);
}
// ...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the moment, your `commandFiles` only contain files inside your `./commands` folder. To create a folder structure like the one below, you'll also need to read content of the folders inside `./commands`.

```
- commands
  - fun
    - game-1.js
    - game-2.js
  - moderation
    - kick.js
    - snipe.js
```

So, first, you read the content of the `commands` folder using [`readdirSync`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdirsync_path_options) and for every returned folder you'll also need to grab the files where the extension is `js`. Check out the code below:

```js
const client = new Discord.Client();
client.commands = new Discord.Collection();

const commandFolders = fs.readdirSync('./commands');

for (const folder of commandFolders) {
  const commandFiles = fs
    .readdirSync(`./commands/${folder}`)
    .filter((file) => file.endsWith('.js'));

  for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(`./commands/${folder}/${file}`);
    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
  }
}
// ...
```